# How do you satisfy the 'lineOrigins' argument in CTFrameGetLineOrigins() in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, unsafemutablepointer, ctframe

I'm trying to figure out `CTFrameGetLineOrigins` from here: [CTFrameGetLineOrigins Got Incorrect Origins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810273/ctframegetlineorigins-got-incorrect-origins), and trying to convert the ObjC to Swift.

Obj-C:

```
CFArrayRef lines = CTFrameGetLines(frame);
size_t numOfLines = CFArrayGetCount(lines);
CGPoint lineOrigins[numOfLines];
CTFrameGetLineOrigins(frame, CFRangeMake(0, 0), lineOrigins);
```

Swift:

```
let lines = CTFrameGetLines(frame)
let numOfLines: size_t = CFArrayGetCount(lines)
let lineOrigins = [CGPoint](repeating: CGPoint.zero, count: numOfLines)
CTFrameGetLineOrigins(frame, CFRangeMake(0, 0), lineOrigins)
```

But I am getting an error for the 3rd parameter of CTFrameGetLineOrigins:
*Cannot convert value of type '[CGPoint]' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer'*

How do I get past this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I just added `&` to the parameter and made the constant a variable.

```
let lines = CTFrameGetLines(frame)
let numOfLines: size_t = CFArrayGetCount(lines)
var lineOrigins = [CGPoint](repeating: CGPoint.zero, count: numOfLines)
CTFrameGetLineOrigins(frame, CFRangeMake(0, 0), &lineOrigins)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
CTFrameGetLineOrigins(frame, CFRangeMake(0, 0), UnsafeMutablePointer(&lineOrigins))
```

or directly

```
CTFrameGetLineOrigins(frame, CFRangeMake(0, 0),&lineOrigins)
```

Comment: Ah yes, I just discovered this. The `UnsafeMutablePointer()` seems to be optional as well.